# How do I hide the status bar on my UIPageViewController? (All view controllers)

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, uipageviewcontroller

I've searched every question/answer I can find on here, but I can't figure out how to hide the status bar for all of the view controllers in my UIPageViewController. Here's the code from my UIPageViewController class:

```
    class TipsVC: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

        lazy var VCArr: [UIViewController] = {
            return [self.VCInstance(name: "T1"),
                    self.VCInstance(name: "T2"),
                    self.VCInstance(name: "T3")]
        }()

        private func VCInstance(name: String) -> UIViewController {
            return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)

 }
        override public func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //self.dataSource = self
            self.delegate = self
            if let OB1 = VCArr.first {
                setViewControllers([OB1], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let pageController = UIPageControl.appearance()
                pageController.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.88, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
                pageController.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.25, blue:0.51, alpha:1.0)
            }


        }

        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
            for view in self.view.subviews {
                if view is UIScrollView {
                    view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
                } else if view is UIPageControl {
                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                }
            }
        }

        public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
            guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }

            let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

            guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
                return VCArr.last
            }

            guard VCArr.count > previousIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            return VCArr[previousIndex]
        }

        public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
            guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArr.index(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }

            let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1

            guard nextIndex < VCArr.count else {
                return VCArr.first
            }

            guard VCArr.count > nextIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            return VCArr[nextIndex]
        }

        public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{

            return VCArr.count

        }

        public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{

            guard let OB1 = viewControllers?.first,
                let OB1Index = VCArr.index(of: OB1) else {
                    return 0

            }

            return OB1Index
        }

        public func nextPageWithIndex(index: Int)
        {
            let nextVC = VCArr[index]
            setViewControllers([nextVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }


    }
```

and here's a code sample from one of my viewControllers:

```
    class T1: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var nextBtn: UIButton!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            super.viewDidAppear(true)
            UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true

        }

        @IBAction func nextBtnDidPress(_ sender: Any) {


            let next = self.parent as! TipsVC
            next.nextPageWithIndex(index: 1)

    }

}
```

I'm well aware of how to hide the status bar on regular view controllers, but I'm unable to get the same results when I'm using a UIPageViewController. What's going on?

Answer (score -1):

To hide statusbar from particluar viewController you need to hide status bar in `viewWillAppear` and hide status bar in `viewWillDisAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}
```

`viewWillAppear` will call before opening particular viewController and `viewWillDisAppear` call after dismiss particular viewController

if you face problem with UIPageViewController use UIViewController and embed UIPageViewController inside that for reference check below code

```
        var pageContainer: UIPageViewController!

        pageContainer = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        pageContainer.delegate = self
        pageContainer.dataSource = self
        pageContainer.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(index: 0)] as [UIViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        pageContainer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        self.view.addSubview(pageContainer.view)
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I put this in the view controller and the UIPageViewController delegate and It's not working.

Comment: can you post your ViewController code snippet that contain PageViewController? for further understanding

Comment: i seems like problem with UIPageViewController instead of using UIPageViewController directly you can use UIViewController which contain pagecontroller answer updated check it once